# How do I Invalidate refresh token for google after changing google password?

Tags: node.js, oauth, google-api

I have written a script for refreshing access token in nodejs. But I am facing an issue, If I change my google password then also I can generate new access token using refresh token. Is there any way I can get some kind of flag saying this user has changed the password. In **NODEJS**.

I just need flow, no need of code. I can code myself.

Thanks,
Ajinkya

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

The whole point of Open authentication is that you the user are granting an application access to your data.  This is independent of your login and password.

The only way for an application to loose access is if the user revokes said access.   Changing the password will not effect access.

No, there is no way of asking Google when the user last changed their password.

How to revoke a refresh token:

1. https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/revoke?token={token}
2. [Apps Connected to your account](https://security.google.com/settings/security/permissions?pli=1)

Comment: Thanks. I have used some flags internally for my output.